# Rotating a plot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

1-How can I rotate my plot so y would be the new x axis and vice versa?

2- Change the maximum value of y axis from 60 to 100.
[image]

The plot is created by this script in the terminal :

```
set palette grey
plot 'color_map.dat' matrix with image
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the transpose of the matrix before plotting it? As for axis scaling, look at the documentation: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node294.html

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered?

Answer (score 1):

You can exchange the x and y axes with the `using` modifier. (Just like for ordinary plots, except that for matrix data, columns 1 and 2 are not in your data file, but are inferred.)

```
plot 'color_map.dat' matrix using 2:1:3 with image
```

If you actually just want to change the maximum value on the y (new x) axis, you would use `set xrange[:100]`. But it sounds like you might actually want to scale the data itself, in which case you could use

```
plot 'color_map.dat' matrix using ($2/60.*100):1:3 with image
```

Try `help plot matrix` for more details.