# gnuplot matrix heat map plot flipped

Tags: plot, gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

when plot

```
set terminal png
set output 'plot.png'
plot 'matrix.txt' matrix with image

  9  3  3  4
  3  1  1  7
  8  9  1  8
  7  3  9  5
```

I get

[image]

Do you see, its rotated / flipped. How align it with data?

I found [Rotating a plot in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402697/rotating-a-plot-in-gnuplot) but solution does not apply here.

Comment: `set yrange [] reverse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to invert the direction of the y axis?

```
set yrange [*:*] reverse
plot 'matrix.txt' matrix with image
```

Or if you want to invert the y coordinates of the matrix but leave the orientation of other plot elements unchanged

```
plot 'matrix.txt' using ($1):(-$2):($3) matrix with image
```